# How to extend dataGridView built in row drag and drop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I've been able to make 2 C# winform datagridviews drag and drop rows between them, but it uses a lot of code.  Now I'm looking at creating a form that will contain 10 such grids, and I'm trying to reuse the code.  I thought I could simply make a sub-class of DataGridView and add the event handlers, but I'm having trouble.

Specifically, how can I override the onDragDrop event, when the only event intellisense sees does not have the correct signature.

I see a signature like: `protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)`, but I'm expecting a signature like `protected override void OnDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)`, because I'm using sender in my code.  What am I missing?  How should I properly override this event?  My non-working code is below:

```
public class DragGrid : DataGridView
{
    private DragGrid()
    {

    }

    private DragGrid(DataTable table)
    {
        this.DataSource = table;
    }

    protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragEnter(e);
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragDrop(e);

        DataGridView grid = sender as DataGridView;
        DataTable table = grid.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataRow row = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataRow)) as DataRow;

        if (row != null && table != null && row.Table != table)
        {
            table.ImportRow(row);
            row.Delete();
            table.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        DragGrid.HitTestInfo info = ((DragGrid)this).HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

        if (info.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataRow view = ((DataTable)(this.DataSource)).Rows[info.RowIndex];

            if (view != null)
            {
                this.DoDragDrop(view, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BOTH ANSWERS BELOW ARE CORRECT AND WORK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making mistake in definition between **events** and **delegates**:
`protected override void OnDragEnter(DragEventArgs e) { }` is a **method** which invokes the [event `DragEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragenter.aspx) of your datagrid.
And when this **event** accurs, all the **delegates** with signature `protected override void OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) { }` are invoked.

So you can't override the event - this is just a field. You can override method which invokes it, but I think this is not that you are seeking for. I suggest you to add a handler for the `DragEnter` event for your script during your constructor:

```
private DragGrid(DataTable table)
{
    this.DataSource = table;
    this.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(_onDragEnter);
}
private void _onDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: -Ok, how should I override the method?

Comment: -Give error: `Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler' M:\Projects\FlexoInventoryManagement\FlexoInventoryManagement\DragGrid.cs 15 31 FlexoInventoryManagement`

Comment: -Should I still reference `base.` in my methods?

Comment: @MAW74656 I think it will do something. It hard to say without complete solution. Also I suggest you not to use the `base.` in your event handler - only if you will use override for the `OnDragEnter`

Answer (score 1):

The override is within the DataGridView itself. Simply replace 'sender' with 'this' and you will be all set.

Comment: -Well it actually builds now.  I'll try it out with multiple grids.